# Proper Python Pandas read_csv encoding for '\u2116', the 'Numero Sign'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, anaconda, importerror

I'm working with a file that has a couple Numero Signs in it.

Here are the top 3 lines copied and pasted directly from the CSV file:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
    â„– Summer  01 !    02 !    03 !    Total   â„– Winter  01 !    02 !    03 !    Total   â„– Games   01 !    02 !    03 !    Combined total
AfghanistanÂ (AFG)  13  0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   13  0   0   2   2
```

When I try to import the file in Anaconda using Python 3.5 using Pandas read_csv I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError:  'charmap' code can't encode character '\u2116' in position 104: character maps to <undefined>
```

This happens when I try:

```
df=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding='utf_8')
```

I also tried the standard English codecs listed here with basically the same error code:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

What should I try differently?

Comment: Can you post a line of the raw data, presumably you also tried `'utf-16'` also?

Comment: @EdChum, added and thank you for looking at this for me!

Comment: When I encode those lines to utf-8 then it decodes correctly, are you able to post a link to the raw file?

Comment: @EdChum, please try here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1NWZtaDIxb1djaU0
Thank you,

Comment: just FYI: in Python 2.7 and pandas 0.19.0 I can load the provided file without any issues.

Comment: I can read this csv fine using `encoding='utf-8'` using python 3.4 64-bit so I don't know what the issue here other than it may be a display issue your end, what version of python are you using?

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot of my code, error message, and the info returned after entering 'conda info'  - hopefully this helps and you guys can see exactly what's going on.  Thank you for helping me, I'm stumped and know the issue is probably between the computer screen and my chair :P

Comment: Also, I am able to open another CSV file in the same folder with the same code and have uploaded it, 'mpg.csv',. in case it helps.  Thank you!

Comment: For any future readers, I went in the CSV file and deleted the 'Numero Sign' from the file and used it that way.  Hopefully it doesn't present a problem in future projects.
Thanks everyone for chiming in,
Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went in the CSV file and deleted the 'Numero Sign' from the file and used it that way. Hopefully it doesn't present a problem in future projects.